# Python: How to copy specific files from one location to another and keep directory structure

Tags: python

Hi I'm struggling with some python code for to copy specific files in a folder to another folder whilst keeping the directory structure.

I'm learning so this code is put together using various code snippets I've found, I couldn't find anything that exactly matched my circumstance and I don't understand python enough yet to understand where I've gone wrong

```
def filtered_copy(src_dir, dest_dir, filter):
print 'Copying files named ' + filter + ' in ' + src_dir + ' to ' + dest_dir
ignore_func = lambda d, files: [f for f in files if isfile(join(d, f)) and f != filter]
if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    print 'deleting existing data'
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)
copytree(src_dir, dest_dir, ignore=ignore_func)
```

Executing this code like this

```
filtered_copy(c:\foldertosearch, c:\foldertocopyto, 'settings.xml')
```

does copy across the file I want but does not copy across the parent folder i.e. the src_dir, so the result I'm trying to achieve is:

c:\foldertocopyto\foldertosearch\settings.xml

*** Edit - to clarify this is a script that will be used on multiple operating systems

So if the folder structure was more complex i.e.

Parent folder
-subfolder
--subsubfolder
----subsubsubfolder
------settings.xml

and I ran

```
filtered_copy(subsubsubfolder, foldertocopyto, 'settings.xml')
```

I would want the new folder structure to be

foldertocopyto (there could be more parent folders above this or not)
--subsubsubfolder
----settings.xml

In other words the folder I search for a specific file in should also be copied across and if that folder already exists it should be deleted before the folder and file is copied across

I assumed copytree() would do this part - but obviously not!

*** end of Edit

*** Latest code changes

This works but I'm sure it's a long-winded way, also it copies blank folders, presumably because of the copytree() execution, I'd prefer just the folder that's being searched and the filtered file...

```
def filtered_copy(src_dir, dest_dir, filter):
foldername = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(src_dir))
print 'Copying files named ' + filter + ' in ' + src_dir + ' to ' + dest_dir + '/' + foldername
ignore_func = lambda d, files: [f for f in files if isfile(join(d, f)) and f != filter]
if os.path.exists(dest_dir + '/' + foldername):
    print 'deleting existing data'
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)
copytree(src_dir, dest_dir + '/' + foldername, ignore=ignore_func)
```

*** end of latest code changes

Comment: why not `git init` and `git clone`?

Comment: what if instead it was `C:\Users\ASDASD\.AppData\folder_to_search` what would you expect

Comment: Not sure I understand how you want this to behave in a every use case. Suppose you feed in "C:\a\b\c", "C:\a\b\d\e", "some.txt" Then would you want it to create a folder called: "C\a\b\d\e" for "some.txt" to be copied to?

Comment: **skywalker** - cant use git, will be run on multiple operating systems **Andrew** - Edited my question, it should always copy the immediate parent folder i,e, the one I'm searching in and any sub folders that it finds the file I request in the script

Comment: maybe this script/library will be useful? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsync.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`. It works just fine and you don't have to pass every argument, only src and dst are mandatory.

However in your case you can't use a similar tool like `shutil.copytree` because it behaves differently: as the destination directory must not exist this function can't be used for overwriting its contents

Give a try to a sample code below:

```
def recursive_overwrite(src, dest, ignore=None):
if os.path.isdir(src):
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest)
    files = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored = ignore(src, files)
    else:
        ignored = set()
    for f in files:
        if f not in ignored:
            recursive_overwrite(os.path.join(src, f), 
                                os.path.join(dest, f), 
                                ignore)
else:
    shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

Comment: I get a 'str' object is not callable when I call like this recursive_overwrite(subsubsubfolder, foldertocopyto, ignore='settings.xml')